# Raspbian Jessi apt-get install python2.7-minimal configure error

Tags: python-2.7, raspbian, apt-get

I have installed Raspbian Jessi with Seafile, which is dependent on python2.7, installed as part of this process by myself. It was working fine for weeks when it was in headless mode. After running manually via ssh

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

the update process fails with a configuration error of python2.7-minimal. the output was:

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7 python2.7-minimal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libpython-stdlib
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
Suggested packages:
  python2.7-doc binfmt-support
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python2.7 python2.7-minimal
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,402 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,595 kB of additional disk space will be used.
y
Selecting previously unselected package python2.7-minimal.
(Reading database ... 107629 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python2.7-minimal_2.7.9-2+deb8u1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7-minimal (2.7.9-2+deb8u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python2.7.
Preparing to unpack .../python2.7_2.7.9-2+deb8u1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7 (2.7.9-2+deb8u1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...
Setting up python2.7-minimal (2.7.9-2+deb8u1) ...
Sorry: TypeError: compile() expected string without null bytesdpkg: error processing package python2.7-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python2.7:
 python2.7 depends on python2.7-minimal (= 2.7.9-2+deb8u1); however:
  Package python2.7-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python2.7 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7-minimal
 python2.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried several combinations of apt-get remove/purge, dpkg reconfigure etc but the error is persistent.

Another thing:

```
apt-cache policy python2.7-minimal python2.7
python2.7-minimal:
  Installed: 2.7.9-2+deb8u1
  Candidate: 2.7.9-2+deb8u1
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.9-2+deb8u1 0
        500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
python2.7:
  Installed: 2.7.9-2+deb8u1
  Candidate: 2.7.9-2+deb8u1
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.9-2+deb8u1 0
        500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I am not a beginner but also not an expert with Linux in general. Tell me if you need any further information to answer this question. Please help because I am tired of fighting stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/685695/python2-7-issue-after-updating-debian-to-jessie) and [this blog](https://notesofsysadmin.wordpress.com/2016/08/03/dependency-issue-python2-7-ubuntu-14-04/), it seems likely that there is something wrong with your local files (corruption, mis-configuration, etc). You said that you tried purging the packages, but since I'm not sure exactly what you tried, I would suggest purging all python packages with `sudo apt purge python*`, and then reinstalling them as necessary.
It is worth noting for anybody not aware that `apt purge` will completely uninstall a package, including configuration files. So don't do this unless you understand the risk.

Comment: already did this (should have been more specific above). sadly no effect. also, purging python removes like tons of other packages, which might break somethign elsewhere..

Comment: Maybe try the steps from the solution in the first link, then?

"This was caused by a corrupt file.

I installed debsums, and ran it on all files. Grepping on FAILED.

One of the corrupt files was topics.py (/usr/lib/python2.7/pydoc_data/topics.py).

I transferred the file from another, working machine, to that one, and reinstalled python2.7"